# Data Protection when indexing and querying your own documents using LlamaIndex and LangChain

Tags: openai-api, langchain, llama-index

we have some sensitive data which we want to Data Ingestion, Data Indexing locally on prem but should not be sent externally from the company network  In this case such as langchain.vectorstores stores locally for Data Ingestion, Data Indexing what sort of information goes externally to openAI or outside company network

Answer (score 0):

The data is sent at least to OpenAI. Also, I did not review all the packages to see if there is another place where the data is sent. Also, you are inserting an API key into the package, I did not review how the package handles this key, but this might also be a problem.